# C++ wxwidgets comparing wxstrings

Tags: c++, compare, wxwidgets, codeblocks, wxstring

I am trying to compare wxstrings to determine what my program will do.  The string I am comparing is based on a file I am reading in and is the only line in the file.

I am using codeblocks with wxSmith activated.

This is the section of my program that I am trying to get working.

```
void Disc_MasterFrame::OncdiscClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    system("sh detect-disc.sh");

    wxString file;
    file << wxT("detect-disc");
    wxTextFile tfile;
    tfile.Open(file);
    detectdiscw=tfile.GetFirstLine();

    //std::ifstream myfile ("detect-disc");
    //getline (myfile,detectdisc);
    //myfile.close();

    cd << wxT("An audio cd was inserted.");
    dvd << wxT("A dvd was inserted.");

    if (detectdiscw == cd){
        //musicrip->Show();
        //this->Disc_MasterFrame::ripmusic();
        void ripmusic();
    }
    else if (detectdiscw == dvd)
    {
        manipdvd->Show();
        void dvdmanip();
    }
}

void Disc_MasterFrame::ripmusic()
{
    musicrip->Show();
    system("sh disc-info.sh");
    ...
```

When the button is clicked, the script should run, it does because it generates a file using the cdde command (linux/ubuntu cli program).
The result of this command is "An audio cd was inserted." so I have consistency when testing.

Then it opens and reads the file and attempts to compare it to two predefined strings.
Once that is done it should 'show' one of two panels already created.

I pretty sure I'm doing something wrong because it just sits there after the button is clicked.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That seems like a frustrating problem.  Have you stepped through the code with a debugger?  This will often show you exactly where the code is going wrong and even make the fix obvious.  Try it and let us know where the problem is.

Comment: Why do you have `void` before your calls to `ripmusic` and `dvdmanip`?  If your ignoring return values, you should use `(void)` to cast the return value (note the parens).

Comment: Try adding a *print* statement inside a final `else` clause.  You could better see the issue if you converted your `if`-`then` ladder to a `switch` statement.  In other words, what happens if the value of `detectdiscw` is not cd or dvd but something else?

Answer (score 0):

In a wxString, the << is appending a string to the existing value (similar to what + would do but with a handy type conversion if needed). I am not sure this is what you actually want to do. If you want to assign a new value to your string, then you should replace the << with =

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies within your lines

```
void ripmusic();
```

and

```
void dvdmanip();
```

You intend to call these functions, but those are **function declarations**, not function calls. In other words, they do nothing. Your functions `ripmusic` and `dvdmanip` are never called.